# Converting numpy image to PIL image giving strange result

Tags: python, django, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

Actually, I need to save PIL image to django that's why I am converting numpy image to pillow image but it's giving me the strange image. I have tried to convert image using below code which gives strange image response.

```
    from cv2 import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import urllib.request
    from PIL import Image

    url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Deepika_Padukone_at_Tamasha_event.jpg/220px-Deepika_Padukone_at_Tamasha_event.jpg"
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    img77 = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    img77 = cv2.imdecode(img77, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


    ''' join image '''

    im_h = cv2.hconcat([img77, img77])



    ''' resize image '''
    print('Original Dimensions : ',im_h.shape)
    
    width = 1108 #554 #1108
    height = 584 #292 #584
    dim = (width, height)

    resized = cv2.resize(im_h, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)
    


    ''' put similarity level '''
    img1 = resized
    img2 = cv2.imread('percentage_images\\15.png') # it's percentage image(.png)

    rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
    roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]


    img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)


    img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)


    img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)


    dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
    img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst

    nadu = Image.fromarray(img1,"RGB")
    print(nadu)
    nadu.save("what.jpg")


    # Image.fromarray(img1).convert("RGB").save("what2.jpg")

    cv2.imshow('res',img1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # cv2.imwrite('full_edit.jpg', img1)
```

Image convert from this ->
[image]
to this->
[image]

Comment: **Can't reproduce the error using the given code** (the image looks right), but, most likely, the error is related to some issue regarding the color channel ordering: OpenCV uses BGR color ordering, whereas nearly every library else uses RGB color ordering. Maybe check other code parts, which might not be shown here, for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HansHirse yeah i understand what happening , we have to convert cv2 image from BGR form to RGB form, only after that we can process it with pillow lib(which uses RGB form).

```
img11 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)#edited -> img1 to img11
nadu = Image.fromarray(img11) #edited -> img1 to img11
```